# Select next visible row (like pressing {down})

Tags: excel, vba, row, filtered

I've done a ton of reseach and I've found a code that worked partially for me.
All I want is a code that simply go to the **next cell below** but the rows are **filtered**.
The problem with this code is that it goes to the very first row (header) and then it offsets to the next below line.

```
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    Range("E" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Select
End With
```

I hope the code does this, but the rows are **not** consecutives:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to loop through visible cells of a specific column?

Comment: at the time I didn't know I had to loop to achieve what I needed, I wanted to simply go down one cell on a filtered table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent all night google-ing and reading docs about `Do While` with the idea of using `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True` and there's the final idea:

> ```
> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Activate 'because I want to activate column "E"
> Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
>   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
> Loop
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I googled it for you!

```
Sub GoToNextVisibleCellBelow()

    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Don't loop! There's a better way to do this!

The SendKeys keyword will instruct the application to mimic a key press or combination of key presses. In your case you'll want to use:

```
SendKeys "{Down}"
```

This way you can "press down key" and move down one visible cell.

See documentation for more info on how to use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement